Predict quality of a product, from production line, by looking at a sample instead of the whole batch
I have a machine that produces cartons. Every batch that is produced is of 3000 cartons.
I want to determine what percentage of cartons are GOOD and what percentage are NOT GOOD ( marks on the carton, hole etc) by looking at a sample of the batch instead of all cartons one by one.
What is known is:
A confidence level of 95% is preferred
Is there a way to do it by having a sample size of 30 to 40 cartons ?

Welcome to Cross Validated! Have you seen proportion confidence intervals?

You could also look up Proportions Test or Standard Error of a Proportion.
